# Karbon Smart Tablet 1- Problem

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet

I have an Karbon Smart Tablet 1 - Android version 4.0.3. 
Most of the applications like Watsapp, Viber, doesn't work. Whenever i try to install these apps from Google play store , it shows " YOUR DEVICE IS NOT COMPATIBLE".
Is there any solution for this problem ?, Pls suggest guys >>
THanks in advance

Comment: The apps you name most likely need to access your *phone number* -- but your tablet cannot provide such, as it has no telephony functionality. You could try, however, to install them on your phone, extract the `.apk` of the apps with e.g. [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager), and side-load it to your tablet. While this way the apps might *install*, they might still have problems running (without being able to access your phone number).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Converted from my comment, as there were no other answers:</sup>

The apps you name most likely need to access your *phone number*, or using *SMS* to unlock their features – but your tablet cannot provide such, as it has no telephony functionality.

You could try, however, to install them on your phone, extract the `.apk` of the apps with e.g. [AppMonster](http://www.appbrain.com/app/de.android_telefonie.appmanager), and side-load it to your tablet. While this way the apps might *install*, they might still have problems running (without being able to access your phone number), or even might refuse starting up at all.